# Avoiding conflicting namespace and class name

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, naming, namespace

Say I am developing a Calculator application.  It has one class called: `Calculator`.  Therefore my namespace structure would look like this:

```
MyCompany.Calculator.Core.Calculator
```

Unfortunately, this is not right because the same name should not be used for a namespace and a type in it.  This is thoroughly explained in [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731415/namespace-and-class-with-the-same-name). One of the [answer to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24550062/3723423) suggests to solve the ambiguity by using an `Util` suffix for the namespace, which would then look like this:

```
MyCompany.CalculatorUtil.Core.Calculator
```

This solves the naming ambiguity in the programming language.  However, this kind of naming is in contradiction with good DDD naming practices:  because `Util` seems to be a "*weasel word*" according to [this article on naming in the ubiquitous language](http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2017/06/07/naming-and-ubiquitous-language/) and these should be avoided.

What is the best way to avoid a conflict here in the case of a Calculator?

The application I am developing is much more complex than a simple calculator, however the principle still stands.

Comment: "I am developing a Calculator application"  "The application I am developing is much more complex than a simple calculator."  I think you've answered it on your own.  Give your namespace a proper name to represent "much more complex than a simple calculator".

Comment: @Neil, the principle still stands to the application I am developing.

Comment: If you choose some appropriate name, all conflicts can be avoided by the _client_ of your classes, by simply using the full qualified name if necessary.

Comment: Tell us what other leaf classes there are besides `Calculator`, and we'll tell you what to call the higher-level package.

Comment: You can resolve the namespace problem both in this case and *in principle* by providing a more comprehensive name to the namespace. No  set can contain itself, and the relationship of a class to a namespace should be considered a component of a whole module.  Therefore the names shouldn't clash if named properly.

Comment: Me hate namespaces. :-D It's a feature I never understood the point of so much, especially in C++ when there's ADL involved which complicates things even further. I like just adding a prefix to the names at global scope, like `DrunkAllocator` instead of `Allocator`. I've used a lot of third party C libs in a single source file from time to time and never got a conflict with `DrunkAllocator`. The probability of that happening seems so low and the fix seems so quick (since it would fail builds) in such an astronomically improbable case that namespaces seem like such overkill for this problem.

Comment: I had a former colleague try to explain it to me by comparing file systems, suggesting why it would be horrible to download all files to a single folder and the probability of conflict. But that's not a fair analogy, because each TU/source file basically lives in its own folder. It only needs to include/import whatever it needs, and so the probability of name conflicts, especially if things are named with a prefix naming convention to astronomically further reduce the probability of clashing, seems to be so ridiculously low... and again the fix so simple in such an improbable event.

Comment: The Java naming conventions recommend lowercase for packages and capitalized class names, and using a reversed domain name as package root, e.g. com.stackexchange.softwareengineering.calculator.core.Calculator. Then there's no conflict. But your wording and example namespace suggest that you're using maybe C#, where you have conventions differing from Java :-(.

Comment: @DrunkCoder In large applications, your prefix cannot be too short and you always have to use the 'fully qualified' name - can't really tell the compiler 'using myfncprefix'. It works, but I wouldn't call it ideal.

Comment: Also: I *really* hope you actually do call it 'DrunkAllocator' and don't just use this as an example ;-)

Comment: It's designed to allocate beer. :-D Agreed that having to stick the prefix in all the time can get fugly, though lengthy namespace qualifiers can be too -- just depends how we name them. An underscore can be used in place of a dot, for example, like `fnc_something` in place of `fnc.something`. For me namespaces do come with the benefit of nesting and being able to abbreviate their names in a way back where we don't have to repeatedly refer to the namespaces involved, but dunno... at the end of the day I still find myself liking the plain old prefix naming convention better.

Comment: ... that said, my dislike for namespaces came from ADL issues specific to how C++ treats namespaces. It implicitly looks into namespaces for identifiers at times, and in a former company I worked in, we actually had more clashes and build errors across compilers and platforms once we started organizing everything into namespaces than before when we used plain old prefixes.

Comment: However, I really don't think a namespace needs a long name, or be deeply nested, or that a prefix needs to be long, to reduce the probability of clashing to a negligible minimum. We can never reduce probability to zero even with the most deeply nested namespaces. Even three character prefixes astronomically reduce the chance of one source file importing/including something else with the same name. What are the odds of one source file including/importing two `dwc_tree` identifiers even in a codebase with 10mil LOC and 100 third party dependencies? In practice I've never won such a lottery.

Comment: Since `dwc` isn't chosen randomly, I do usually reserve 3 letter prefixes for core 'namespaces'. Anyway, I think we're getting a bit off topic.

Comment: I'm a master at being off-topic! BTW, do you guys like tactical RPGs?

Comment: You can follow the pattern `<org domain>.<app name>.<functionality>` as parent namespace for your app classes. In case of a library, use library name in place of app name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the name of your application 'Calculator'? if it is you may find that that name has already been used.

I would also advise you NOT to use myCompany as part of the namespace. I know  its a standard way but company names change.

Just have:

```
MyApplicationsRealName.App
MyApplicationsRealName.LibraryName.ClassName
```

Comment: What if the application's name changes?

Comment: of course this can happen, but in my experience it is less likely. Companies get bought, sold and rebranded much more often than they change the name of the products and sometimes a new product name means new code anyway

Comment: also, its just the one application that you need to deal with. not every bit of code the company has ever written

Comment: I guess we could argue whether you actually need to change the namespace when the company's name changes, but my question wasn't really serious. I think your suggestion should work fine. Unless, of course, you have an `App` class - then you're in trouble...

Comment: you do have an App class. MyApplicationsRealName.App

Comment: My bad! I assumed this was the project that produces the executable. Okay, I'm out of objections, fake or otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

> Say I am developing a Calculator application. It has one class called: Calculator

What do you think will the class name `Calculator` stand for? What do expect to find there, just by reading that name? The UI, the domain logic, data, application start code? You cannot tell, this class name is way too ambigous to make sense.

So if I were going to design a Calculator application, there could be an `CalculatorDialog` class for the UI, a `CalculatorController` or `CalculatorLogic` for the domain logic, a `CalculatorPresenter` or `CalculatorViewModel` when making an MVP or MVVM architecture, and a `CalculatorState` if you decide to put the state explictly in some object for persistence. There may be further infrastructure classes like a `Program` class for the application's entry point.  But not a class called `Calculator`, this name makes only sense at the namespace level, but not at the class level.

This is not restricted to this specific example. A program or library consists always of different parts - so give those parts a name which distinguish them clearly from the program name and makes them distinguishable from other parts, then the problem won't occur.